# Making a search function filter a deep nested object item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, object, search

I'm trying to make a search function in my React application to filter out an item by checking items inside it in an array. I had ideas of using `.filter()` and `.includes()` to map out the specific items in search. However, the object pulled from the backend has the item that users will search very deeply nested.

Here is an example of the object with the item I am trying to filter commented:

```
const x = [
  {
    owner: "76561198111463361",
    sold: true,
    inventory: [
      {
        name: "AK-47 | Redline", //User may look for this
        price: 1369,
      },
      {
        name: "StatTrak™ AWP | Asiimov", //User may look for this
        price: 8050,
      },
    ],
    name: "m",
    password: "e",
  },
  {
    owner: "76561198111463361",
    sold: true,
    inventory: [
      {
        name: "AK-47 | Redline", //User may look for this
        price: 1369,
      },
      {
        name: "StatTrak™ AWP | Asiimov", //User may look for this
        price: 8050,
      },
    ],
    name: "m",
    password: "e",
  },
];
```

How could I filter these?

Comment: what u have done ? add code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you want to filter it also share your desired output for better clarity.

```js
var data=[{owner: "76561198111463361",sold: true,inventory: [{ name: "AK-47 | Redline", }, { name: "StatTrak™ AWP | Asiimov",}],name: "m",password: "e",},{owner: "76561198111463361",sold: true,inventory: [{ name: "AK-47 | Redline", }, { name: "StatTrak™ AWP | Asiimov",}],name: "m",password: "e"}];

var string = 'Redline';

result = data.filter(val=>val.inventory.some(k=>k.name.toUpperCase().includes(string.toUpperCase())));

console.log(result);
```

Please let me know if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the owner information with it,
    `x.filter(item => item.inventory.find(data => data.name.indexOf(searchKeyword) !== -1))`, if you want something more specific please comment down

Answer (score 0):

You can map and filter data.

```js
const findInventory = (data, fn) => {
  return data.reduce((array, item) => {
    let inventory = item.inventory;
    if (fn !== undefined) {
      inventory = inventory.map(fn);
    }
    array = array.concat(inventory);
    return array;
  }, []);
};

const data = [{"owner":"76561198111463361","sold":true,"inventory":[{"name":"AK-47 | Redline","price":1369},{"name":"StatTrak™ AWP | Asiimov","price":8050}],"name":"m","password":"e"},{"owner":"76561198111463361","sold":true,"inventory":[{"name":"AK-47 | Redline","price":1369},{"name":"StatTrak™ AWP | Asiimov","price":8050}],"name":"m","password":"e"}];

// Get objects
console.log(findInventory(data));
// get names
console.log(findInventory(data, (i) => i.name));
```

Second example:

```js
const findInventory = (data, mapper, filter) => {
  return data.reduce((array, item) => {
    let inventory = item.inventory;
    if (mapper !== undefined && filter !== undefined) {
      inventory = inventory.map(mapper).filter(filter);
    }
    array = array.concat(inventory);
    return array;
  }, []);
};

const data = [{"owner":"76561198111463361","sold":true,"inventory":[{"name":"AK-47 | Redline","price":1369},{"name":"StatTrak™ AWP | Asiimov","price":8050}],"name":"m","password":"e"},{"owner":"76561198111463361","sold":true,"inventory":[{"name":"AK-47 | Redline","price":1369},{"name":"StatTrak™ AWP | Asiimov","price":8050}],"name":"m","password":"e"}];

// Get objects
console.log(findInventory(data));
// get names by filter
console.log(findInventory(data, (i) => i.name, (name) => name.indexOf("AK-") !== -1));
```